# Check existence of duplicated items with XQuery

Tags: xquery

I'm doing some exercises on XQuery and I can't figure out how to deal with this problem.
Let's say I have a FileSystem structured like this DTD: *(Unspecified elements only contain PCData)*

```
<!ELEMENT RootFolder ( File | Folder )* >
<!ELEMENT File ( Name, Type, Size, CreationDate, OwnerId )>
<!ELEMENT Folder ( Name, CreationDate (File | Folder)* ) >
```

How can I write a function that returns true/false checking whether the names of every resource (files and folders) are such that all of them have a distinct pathname?

Comment: Well, you can group by the pathname (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by) and if there is a group containing more than one item you have duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for uniqueness, you could check for duplicates by checking to see if a `Folder` or `File` has a sibling with the same `Name`...

```
declare variable $in :=
    <RootFolder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>user</Name>
            <File>
                <Name>Fred</Name>
            </File>
            <File>
                <Name>Bill</Name>
            </File>
            <File>
                <Name>Fred</Name>
            </File>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>manager</Name>
            <File>
                <Name>Jane</Name>
            </File>
            <File>
                <Name>Mary</Name>
            </File>
            <File>
                <Name>Jane</Name>
            </File>
        </Folder>
    </RootFolder>;

declare function local:hasDupe($ctx as element()) as xs:boolean {
    boolean($ctx//(File|Folder)[Name=following-sibling::*/Name])
    };

local:hasDupe($in)
```

This would return `true`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
declare variable $in :=
      <Folder Name="root">
        <Folder Name="user">
          <File Name="Fred"/>
          <File Name="Bill"/>
          <File Name="Fred"/>
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="manager">
          <File Name="Jane"/>
          <File Name="Mary"/>
          <File Name="Jane"/>
        </Folder>
      </Folder>;

      declare function local:pathName($resource as element()) as xs:string {
        string-join($resource/ancestor-or-self::*/@Name, '/')
      };

      for $resource in $in//(Folder | File)
      let $path := local:pathName($resource)
      group by $path
      where count($resource) gt 1
      return $path
```

returns

```
("root/manager/Jane", "root/user/Fred")
```

(in some undefined order)